# Angular: How can I dynamically change the disabled or visible property of an input type="radio" list?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need some guidance please.

**Details:** I have a list of radio buttons that is displayed using an `*ngFor` loop in Angular. I have a specific use case, where certain of the radio buttons should be disabled. How can I dynamically change the `[disabled]` property of an `input type="radio"` list?

This is my HTML:

```
  <span
    class="form-check-inline radio-buttons-width"
    *ngFor="let paymentInstructionType of paymentInstructionTypes"
  >
    <label class="form-check-label fs-16">
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="form-check-input"
        name="paymentInstructionType"
        ngModel
        [value]="paymentInstructionType"
        [(ngModel)]="model.paymentInstructionType"
        [disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow"
        (ngModelChange)="modelChange('paymentInstructionType', $event)"
      />
      {{ paymentInstructionType.description }}
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </span>
```

This is a list of my radio buttons:

```
  paymentInstructionTypes = [
    { name: 'KeepYourSavingsWhereTheyAre', description: 'Keep Your Savings Where They Are', code: 'W9', defaultRegShow: true },
    { name: 'FullTransfer', description: 'Full Transfer', code: 'W3', defaultRegShow: true},
    { name: 'PartTransfer', description: 'Part Transfer', code: 'W5', defaultRegShow: true},
    { name: 'FullCash', description: 'Withdraw All My Savings', code: 'W4', defaultRegShow: true},
    { name: 'NoPaymentOption', description: 'No Payment Option Selected (Note: This option may only be selected if the member did not submit a claim form.)', code: 'Z', defaultRegShow: false }];
```

**I have tried using the below without luck:**

```
[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow === 'true'"
[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow === true"
[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow"
```

Ultimately I would like to dynamically set the [visible] and [disabled] properties dynamically as my data changes.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am using `(ngModelChange)="modelChange('paymentInstructionType', $event)"` that seems to disable the working of this code in my input: `[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow"`. When I remove the `(ngModelChange)` method call it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: just tried running your code in stackblitz. the line following gave an error, since the app did not know what `model` was ` [(ngModel)]="model.paymentInstructionType"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the issue is... You may wish to restart your code. I ran [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzudqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) using your code, and both `[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow === true"` and `[disabled]="paymentInstructionType.defaultRegShow"` work just fine.

Comment: Ah! i figured out my problem. I left out my line of code for change detection. Didn't think it would make a difference, but in fact it is the reason my code is not working as expected.  I have updated my code. would appreciate it if you could perhaps take a look. apologies

Comment: can you please include the code for `modelChange()`? It may be what is badly affecting your disabled... the code still works with the `onModelChange`